# jquery .submit() and .click() for required input fields

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I used `.submit()` so that the REQUIRED property for input fields will trigger and it works.
But the values I'm passing are not getting through and just passing empty values.

```
$('#add').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: {
            'lastName': $('#lastName').val(),
            'firstName': $('#firstName').val(),
            'address': $('#address').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert("Succes");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

And when I use `.click()` the values are being passed correctly but the problem is the required property for input fields are not being triggered and so the user can submit the form with empty fields even though I used the required property.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the full code plz with HTML part, or create a working live fiddle that reproduces your error

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it inside a form tag and closing the input tag

```
        <form>
          <input type = "text" class = "txtPost" placeholder = "Post a question?" required />
          <button>submit</button>
        </form>
```